# PHP Codeigniter Base_URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help.

Almost finish my final project..

Somehow the gallery meets an error for displaying it's pictures, I thought it's because the base_url

```
<?php
        //FOLDER GALLERY-PART
            $dirname = "./assets/images/gallery/";
            $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

            array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $images), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $images);

            foreach($images as $image) {
                echo //'<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />'; -- Ini cth untuk tampilkan semua gambar (dlm Garis lurus)

        "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 portfolio-item logos'>
            <div class='portfolio-wrapper'>
                <div class='portfolio-single'>
                    <div class='portfolio-thumb'>
                    <img src='.$image.' class='img-responsive' alt=''>
                    </div>
                    <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='" . base_url() . "gallery/delete' method='post'>
                    <div class='portfolio-view'>
                        <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
                            <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-link'></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href='.$image.' data-lightbox='example-set'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class='portfolio-info'>
                    <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='" . base_url() . "gallery/delete' method='post'>
                        <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='$image' />";?>
                        <?php if($_SESSION['admin']==1):?>  
                            <button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='delete fa fa-trash fa-3x'></i></button>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                <?="</form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
    }
  ?>
```

How to put base_url on

```
$dirname
```

Or any other suggestion?

Comment: Where is your assets directory? Is it at root of your project directory?

Comment: Have you looked at the html helper in codeigniter img() http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<img src='".base_url()$image."' class='img-responsive' alt=''>
```

Comment: I have added / before assets. check now

Comment: Instead I delete "assets/images/gallery".Since $image itself already contain the path. It makes double path, so that wouldn't worked. Solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$dirname = "./assets/images/gallery/";
            $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");`
echo '<img src="'.$baseurl/$image.'" /><br />'; ?>
```